# Rotating liquid

Tags: physics

Having a sphere of liquid, no gravity, animated to be rotating, I would have expected the sphere to turn disc shaped.

But it does not, is just keeping shape till eventually parts are ripping off.

Any tips to make a rotating sphere of liquid with no gravity adapt natural donout / double drop shape?